Why does Java java.util.regex Pattern Matcher Throw Runtime Exceptions?
The following code throw a runtime exception in my project
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(null);


Uncaught exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
"java.lang.CharSequence.length()" because "this.text" is null     at
java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1769)    at
java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:415)     at
java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.(Matcher.java:252)    at
java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1134)

In my IDE it says this method is marked @NotNull (see below) which is I assume why it's throwing an exception because my understanding is that if there's a "NotNull validator" on my Classpath it will do this.
My questions are:

Where is the @NotNull annotation even coming from? I don't see it in the JavaDoc - is that actually part of the Java SDK?
How do I know what validator is throwing that exception?
If it's not the validator then why is is throwing an Exception that's not mentioned in the method signature?




no idea where the annotations comes from... not in the source code of OpenJDK; 2) why do you thing there is some validator involved? 3) it is apparently throwing NPE since it is trying to call length() from its input argument


See How does @NotNull add itself in IntelliJ IDEA?. The exception you're seeing has nothing to do with those annotations, it's just a good old-fashioned "trying to call a method on null" error.

Annotations come with IntelliJ IDEA — they are defined in a special annotations.xml files put on the top of JDK, see:
https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/65a7f3883a0bd2b3682720fc5fe5e86cc46dfdd5/java/jdkAnnotations/java/util/regex/annotations.xml#L97-L99

Not really anything to do with IDE - pattern.matcher(null); always throws NPE. Just use pattern.matcher(""); and then you can call matcher.reset(otherString) to re-use same matcher.


@NotNull is a Code-Contract Annotation added by IntelliJ.

The annotation (or its potential validator) is not the one throwing the exception, it only hints you about potential issues at design-time but the code still compiles. Instead, Matcher.getTextLength() is throwing the exception at runtime, as shown in the stack trace.

The exception being thrown is a NullPointerException, subclass of RuntimeException which do not need to be declared in the methods' signatures, in contrary to so-called checked exceptions (it would be pretty verbose to specify each time a NullPointerException can be thrown, although it may still be interesting to make it explicit in some cases).


